# Hardware upgrade for developing android App on Android studio

Tags: android, hardware, upgrade, development-environment

Hello all and thanks to answering my questions...

I am going to enter Android development eco system and i think that my PC is low end and i want to buy a new one.

**Please Tell me do i need to upgrade it??? iF yes, which config i have wroten is needed?? Note that i want to buy new system and not upgrade it for years...**

It's True that more Powerful system is better, but insert budget in your opinion.

at first, My PC specification for now is:

- Mainboard: Gigabyte p3A
- Processor: Intel e5300 dual core @ 2.6Ghz ( Processor don't support HAXM that indeed for Android Studio)
- Memory: 2+1GB @ 333 Mhz
- Old HDD drive with 250 GB capacity

### So i writen spec of two pc:

**1. PC config 1:**

- Mainboard: Asus H81M-c
- Processor: Intel Core i-3-4170 (Amazing !5300 passmark benchmark)
- Memory: 2x4GB @1600Mhz CL7
- SSD Drive: Samsung 850 evo 120 GB

  **2. PC config 2:**
- Mainboard: Asus H97 Plus
- Processor: Intel Core i7-4690 (Amazing 10500 passmark benchmark)
- Memory: 2x4GB @1600Mhz CL7
- SSD Drive: Samsung 850 evo 120 GB

Comment: I want to use onboard intel HD 4xxx vga... is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First off, yes I'd say you should upgrade it. Do you need the upgrade? Well, in my personal experience, you don't absolutely need to upgrade. I created my first app on an ancient 8 year old PC, with 1GB RAM, 3.2Ghz Pentium 4 and onboard Intel graphics running Ubuntu 13.04

Now, my app was a simple one, yet Android Studio took about 3-4 minutes just to compile it. On a modern PC, it would take just 20-30 seconds. So no, its not very easy or smooth, but it at least works.

Now as to your situation. You happen to have a very outdated PC. So, I'd strongly recommend upgrading, for a much smoother experience. Android Studio recommends us to have at least 8GB RAM and some decent processor.

Between the PC config 1 and config 2, they are all the same, just different processors and motherboards. I'd say you should go woth i7 because its more advanced and probably performs better too (check some benchmarks for that, your benchmarks aren't clear enough).

The SSD is a good choice, as it would improve build times.

I also recommend increasing the RAM, to 12GB if you can afford it.

On the Graphics front, you haven't mentioned any specific Graphics chip. Don't go with any onboard graphics though, because you really need some decent graphics card. And who knows, you may want to make games some day. So, buy any decent NVIDIA or Radeon graphics card that you can afford.

And yup, that's it. Its my opinion on the kind of machine you should have. But, this kind of thing is rather subjective, so get all the counsels you can get, and then decide for yourself.

Comment: I can add an standalone graphic card later if i going to making game, but Do i need it for making program??? or will it affect to compiling process???

Comment: Nope. It wouldn't affect the compiling. But, the performance on your AVD (Android Virtual Device) may stutter. Can't be sure though, because I haven't used an AVD on a PC without a graphics card. Anyway, having a graphic card surely speeds up the AVD. It has no effect whatsoever on compile times.